# Facebook Login: "The application has disabled the Oauth client flow for Facebook integration"

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am doing Facebook login integration with my Android app. When I login it gives me the message that "Your application has disabled the Oauth client flow".

My code is like this:

```
package com.example.jiffy;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.facebook.*;
import com.facebook.Session.NewPermissionsRequest;
import com.facebook.Session.OpenRequest;
import com.facebook.Session.StatusCallback;
import com.facebook.model.*;

public class JiffyFacebookLoginActivity extends Activity implements 

StatusCallback{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        OpenRequest open = new OpenRequest(this);
        open.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
        open.setPermissions(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"email"}));
        open.setCallback(this);
        Session s = new Session(this);
        s.openForPublish(open);
    }

    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception 

exception) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 

data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(Session.getActiveSession()!=null)
            Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, 

resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

I have no idea how to correct this.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

You need to enable Client OAuth Login in your Facebook App Settings.
It comes under the product Section. If there is no product. First you have to add the product Facebook Login and then you can enable the login..

Answer (score 6):

You need to enable Client OAuth Login in your Facebook App Settings.
The motivation disable any authentication flows that the app does not use is to minimize attack surface area. When you need to use it, you need enable it.

[image]

Get more details from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security/#surfacearea).

Answer (score 1):

The Facebook App on/off switches for the OAuth settings are now under the "Products -> Facebook Login" section in the developer facebook admin site. https://developers.facebook.com/apps/[YOURFBAPPID]/fb-login/