# Firebase facebook login error logging you into the application after user log out and login again

Tags: java, android, firebase, facebook-android-sdk, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase facebook login for my application when user login from facebook for the very first time it creates account and let user login but after logging user out or if i delete app data and login again it gives error log.

```
fbauth  = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        final LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fbsignup_button);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("email","public_profile");
        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SignupActivity.this, BaseActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    // User is signed in
                    Log.d("", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    Log.d("", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                }
            }
        };
        loginButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                Log.d("FacebookAuthresult", "facebook:onSuccess:" + loginResult);
                handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Log.d("FacebookAuthresult", "facebook:onCancel");
                // ...
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Log.d("FacebookAuthresult", "facebook:onError", error);
                // ...
            }
        });

 private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken token) {
        Log.d("FacebookAuthresult", "handleFacebookAccessToken:" + token);

        AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
        fbauth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d("FacebookAuthresult", "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());


                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                            appsettings appData = new appsettings();
                            if(user.getEmail()!= null)
                                appData.setEmailofuser(user.getEmail());
                            if(user.getDisplayName() != null)
                                appData.setUsername(user.getDisplayName());
                            if(user.getPhotoUrl() != null) {
                                appData.setUriofphoto(user.getPhotoUrl());
                                Log.v("FBReturnedphoto", user.getPhotoUrl().toString());
                                appData.savePreference(getApplicationContext());

                            }


                            Intent intent = new Intent(SignupActivity.this, BaseActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        else {
                            Log.w("FacebookAuthresult", "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        // ...
                    }
                });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

And if i delete user info from firebase console and delete app from facebook app settings it works fine again for the first time only and after signing user out same problem occurs again."

Error Log:

```
08-25 21:07:52.021 19950-19950/android.housekeeping2 D/FacebookAuthresult: facebook:onError
                                                                           Login Error: There is an error in logging you into this application. Please try again later.
                                                                               at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.onActivityResult(LoginManager.java:173)
                                                                               at com.facebook.login.LoginManager$1.onActivityResult(LoginManager.java:139)
                                                                               at com.facebook.internal.CallbackManagerImpl.onActivityResult(CallbackManagerImpl.java:82)
                                                                               at android.housekeeping2.Authentication.SignupActivity.onActivityResult(SignupActivity.java:304)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6456)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3695)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                               at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:102)
08-25 21:07:52.021 19950-19950/android.housekeeping2 D/FirebaseApp: Notifying background state change listeners.
08-25 21:07:52.021 19950-19995/android.housekeeping2 V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 201706171
```

Comment: Post the error log.

Comment: Would you please check now i added error log.

Comment: Greetings! Check bug status. It was resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a reported bug to Facebook tools & support team and it is confirmed. You can now see the status of the bug on [this link.](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/297086380683342/)

You can also see the Stack Overflow question below:

[Login Error: There is an error in logging you into this application. Please try again later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39051517/login-error-there-is-an-error-in-logging-you-into-this-application-please-try/39144831#39144831)

Comment: if i provide the hash key does this error will get fixed?

Comment: No. It is SDK issue. Stay on bug progress.

Comment: i guess this bug is back again ... facing same issue