# Behavior native is not working on the Standalone app

Tags: react-native, facebook-login, expo

I have a problem with facebook login expo
I using expo facebook login and set behavior native. I test on genymotion. It's working
But I build android standalone app and get error. I added key hash facebook and followed these struction on expo documentation. I don't using behavior web.

[image]

Comment: Could you add the error you get?

Comment: ![Valid XHTML](https://scontent.fhan2-4.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/62533434_872202156474608_6788561489138548736_n.jpg?_nc_cat=110&_nc_eui2=AeEBfak4x6SqDGttiJ3qWw30Dtcs62gT763twgesMsK-jSkaddg606WqC9rkpXDwjyyLHfldWJ22gNh7YbSHNIjgFvpmRpSezU0EhUsXt5BL4Q&_nc_oc=AQkAwfCyOfw2xMj88lWOG2ZYvVNw9hypJpaBlkrGexCWawUu8uf-m3ZATCES8daCM_U&_nc_ht=scontent.fhan2-4.fna&oh=235354df207368ebd721ccb6716ff854&oe=5D850132).

Comment: please click Valid XHTML

Comment: have you looked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39051517/login-error-there-is-an-error-in-logging-you-into-this-application-please-try ?

Comment: sorry it not work for me