# App login using Facebook is not working in development! It just loading and Closed- Android Studio

Tags: java, android, authentication, facebook-login

I have implemented an app and I have used facebook login to it. Application is running without crashing but facebook login is not working. When I open up the app and click the facebook login button it will show a progress bar and it will be disappeared immediately without doing anything. I have got the following error in the logcat.

```
2019-08-29 12:45:24.290 19304-19328/com.appic.testfbauth 
E/GraphResponse: 
{
    HttpStatus: 400, 
    errorCode: 100, 
    subErrorCode: 33, 
    errorType: GraphMethodException, 
    errorMessage: Unsupported get request. Object with ID '742177629556035' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api
}
```

refer below for work I have done.

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private LoginButton loginButton;
    private CircleImageView circleImageView;
    private TextView txtName, txtEmail;

    private CallbackManager callbackManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

        loginButton = findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        circleImageView = findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
        txtName = findViewById(R.id.profile_name);
        txtEmail = findViewById(R.id.profile_email);
        checkLoginStatus();

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        // App code
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        // App code
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                        // App code
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    AccessTokenTracker tokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldAccessToken, AccessToken currentAccessToken) {
            if(currentAccessToken == null) {
                txtEmail.setText("");
                txtName.setText("");
                circleImageView.setImageResource(0);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User Logged Out!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else loadUser(currentAccessToken);
        }
    };

    private void loadUser(AccessToken newAccessToken) {
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(newAccessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                try {
                    String first_name = object.getString("first_name");
                    String last_name = object.getString("last_name");
                    String email = object.getString("email");
                    String id = object.getString("id");

                    String image_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/"+ id +"/picture?type=normal";

                    txtEmail.setText(email);
                    txtName.setText(first_name +" "+ last_name);

                    RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
                    requestOptions.dontAnimate();

                    Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(image_url).into(circleImageView);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "first_name,last_name,email,id");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();
    }

    private void checkLoginStatus() {
        if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
            loadUser(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken());
        }
    }
}
```

```xml
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationName"
            android:value="@string/app_name"/>

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
```

I just want to integrate the facebook login and get email, name, image url, id.

Comment: Problem Solved. It happens due to it is in development mode in my developer app in facebook developer. when i build and run a signed apk and change state to release mode it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I have no enough replication for comment so i paste answer. You just give me answers to my below questions.

1. You test your app in real device or emulator.?
2. Get the permission for image?
3. Please check your browser any facebook account already login there?

---

If you not getting email and name please try below code:

```
JSONObject res;

res = new JSONObject(json_object.toString());

String id = res.getString("id");
String name = res.getString("name");
String email = res.getString("email");
```

---

## Update:

- Please Uninstalled FB app from your device and try to login with FB in your app it's working fine.

## Update 25/11/209

- Also please update your hash key - **[Please follow this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39051517/login-error-there-is-an-error-in-logging-you-into-this-application-please-try)**
- After that convert hash key into base 64 - **[tomeko.net](http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php)**

Comment: 1. Yes. Real device 
2. No I didnt get any permissions
3. No

Comment: 1. Which email use for login, 2. Please take permission for images. AND What about my 3rd one question @SasinduLakshitha

Comment: I think it is not about email used to login to facebook and either browser login. How to take image permission?

Comment: At that time i have same issue. in your device Facebook Application is installed ?? @SasinduLakshitha

Comment: Yes. Then how did you fixed it?

Comment: It's not fixed yet. But please uninstall FB application in your device. and try to login in your application with FB. Your login successfully work. Just try and update me.

Comment: Yes it worked fine but it did not show the image, name and email

Comment: lets discuss in chat.

Comment: once logout from browser and uninstaling facebook, both of the solutions worked for me for different projects..