# Facebook SDK login error from Android app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.x, facebook-sdk-3.14.x

I got this error from the Google playstore version of my Android app.
[image]

After adding the key hash in the image in my Facebook developers console, I am getting the same exact error.

[image]

I'd also like to add that I encountered the same error from one of my other Android apps and the problem was fixed just by adding the key hash but now it does not work. This has something to do with Google App Signing in the playstore which is now  a different keystore from our upload keystore. Below is my app signing view in Google Play console see the two signing certificates.

[image]

I tried downloading the .der from the App Signing certificate and then convert that to a keystore to produce a key hash from that and got a different key hash from the Facebook error. I don't know what else to do. Anybody experience this?

UPDATE: Now I'm just getting the error below after I uploaded an update to my app.

UPDATE 2: Tried deleting my app in Facebook settings also deleted the actual Facebook app from my phone (got the idea from the comments) and it worked! Anyway I can programmatically force the FB sdk to not open the FB app?

[image]

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39051517/login-error-there-is-an-error-in-logging-you-into-this-application-please-try

Comment: check you have done this all steps or not: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23863110/6021469

Comment: create facebook key hash after downloading app from playstore. Then add that key to facebook developer account.