# Flutter: Facebook login not working due to key hash

Tags: flutter, facebook, flutter-dependencies

Since Facebook support doesn't help at all I'll have to ask this here.

I have an Android/iOS app that working fine with Facebook login. This was done using this package:

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_facebook_auth

Everything was working fine until I got some complains from Facebook saying this wasn't working anymore and I'll have to update my key hash. They provide this command:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias MY_ALIAS -keystore MY_PATH/.KEY | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

This shows up a hey hash that I copied to Facebook console:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbHT9.png

But Facebook still complaining about the login that doesn't work showing me an old hash:
[image]

App is in development mode but I cannot move to live again due to "You may not make your app available to all users". Also:
"We've disabled this app for violating the Facebook Platform Policies. You can continue to use it in development mode. Read more or appeal"

What else should I change?

Comment: added some info about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have same problem and finally solved. It was take all day :(

Solution; When you generating development key you have to set password as "android". After that, add generated key to the Facebook.

I found the solution on this video; https://youtu.be/zJafRhMhyjM?t=252 at 4:12

And the same solution here; [Login Error: There is an error in logging you into this application. Please try again later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39051517/login-error-there-is-an-error-in-logging-you-into-this-application-please-try#comment65572951_39076791)

Comment: I resolved this a while ago but can't remember how so I'll approve this anyway :)