# Facebook key hash does not match any stored key hashes - Flutter RELEASE

Tags: android, flutter, facebook, hash, facebook-login

I am trying to log in using Facebook to the app created with Flutter,

if I use the debug version of the app, the login works, but if I download the release version I get this error "Facebook key hash does not match any stored key hashes" with a hash key, I put the key on the https://developers.facebook.com/apps/APP_ID/settings/basic/ but still not working.

Can you help me?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into tha issue that when I upload my APK to Play Store and install app
from it,  it shows some Login failed error meanwhile it does work in debug mode.

What you have to do:

- Go to Play console - [link](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/)
- Select Release Management → App Signing
- You can see SHA1 key in hex format App signing certificate.
- Copy the SHA1 in hex format and convert it in to base64 format, you can use this
  [link](http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php) do that without the SHA1: part of the hex.
- Go to Facebook developer console and add the key (after convert to base 64) in the settings → basic → key hashes

Solved this thanks to [mouzmisadiq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1661811/mouzmisadiq) and [gustavo-lopes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8038345/gustavo-lopes)

[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39051517/login-error-there-is-an-error-in-logging-you-into-this-application-please-try)